# How can I change the terminal color in 64-bit Linux when using YASM assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, yasm

Im trying to change the colour of the terminal based on a number of 1 to 5 inputed by the user but it just doesnt work.

Sorry i dont really understand assembly but need to do this for a project and cant understand what is wrong with it.

Its only supposed to change to this colors that i use in the code. It doesnt even reset the terminal color so i dont know how to make it work.

```
section .data
    reset_color db "\033[0m"  ; ANSI escape code to reset colors
    bg_red db "\033[41m"     ; ANSI escape code for red background color
    bg_green db "\033[42m"   ; ANSI escape code for green background color
    bg_yellow db "\033[43m"  ; ANSI escape code for yellow background color
    bg_blue db "\033[44m"    ; ANSI escape code for blue background color
    bg_magenta db "\033[45m" ; ANSI escape code for magenta background color

section .bss
    number resb 1            ; Variable to store the user-selected number

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Reset terminal attributes
    mov rax, 1       ; sys_write
    mov rdi, 1       ; stdout
    mov rsi, reset_color
    mov rdx, 4       ; length of the string
    syscall

    ; Display a prompt to enter a number
    mov rax, 1       ; sys_write
    mov rdi, 1       ; stdout
    mov rsi, prompt
    mov rdx, prompt_len
    syscall

    ; Read the user input
    mov rax, 0       ; sys_read
    mov rdi, 0       ; stdin
    mov rsi, number
    mov rdx, 1       ; read one byte
    syscall

    ; Convert the input to a number
    movzx eax, byte [number]
    sub eax, '0'

    ; Change the background color based on the selected number
    cmp eax, 1
    je change_to_red
    cmp eax, 2
    je change_to_green
    cmp eax, 3
    je change_to_yellow
    cmp eax, 4
    je change_to_blue
    cmp eax, 5
    je change_to_magenta

    ; Invalid input, display an error message
    mov rax, 1       ; sys_write
    mov rdi, 1       ; stdout
    mov rsi, error_message
    mov rdx, error_message_len
    syscall
    jmp exit_program

change_to_red:
    ; Change the background color to red
    mov rax, 1       ; sys_write
    mov rdi, 1       ; stdout
    mov rsi, bg_red
    mov rdx, 5       ; length of the string
    syscall
    jmp exit_program

change_to_green:
    ; Change the background color to green
    mov rax, 1       ; sys_write
    mov rdi, 1       ; stdout
    mov rsi, bg_green
    mov rdx, 5       ; length of the string
    syscall
    jmp exit_program

change_to_yellow:
    ; Change the background color to yellow
    mov rax, 1       ; sys_write
    mov rdi, 1       ; stdout
    mov rsi, bg_yellow
    mov rdx, 5       ; length of the string
    syscall
    jmp exit_program

change_to_blue:
    ; Change the background color to blue
    mov rax, 1       ; sys_write
    mov rdi, 1       ; stdout
    mov rsi, bg_blue
    mov rdx, 5       ; length of the string
    syscall
    jmp exit_program

change_to_magenta:
    ; Change the background color to magenta
    mov rax, 1       ; sys_write
    mov rdi, 1       ; stdout
    mov rsi, bg_magenta
    mov rdx, 5       ; length of the string
    syscall

exit_program:
    ; Exit the program
    mov rax, 60      ; sys_exit
    xor rdi, rdi     ; exit code 0
    syscall

section .data
    prompt db "Enter a number (1-5): ", 0
    prompt_len equ $-prompt

    error_message db "Invalid input!", 0
    error_message_len equ $-error_message
```

Comment: The good news is, that's a pretty solid program avoiding most of the mistakes people make. However, the assembler doesn't do escape processing so treats your `\033` literally. The fix is easy: just split it out in front as a numeric constant such as `db 0o33, "[0m"`.

Comment: What language DO you use?  You can do this job in much the same way in about 10 lines of Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Jester showed in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353881/how-can-i-change-the-terminal-color-in-64-bit-linux-when-using-yasm-assembly#comment134640735_76353881), you can write that `\033` as the literal number 27 in the `db` lines:

```
section .data
    reset_color db 27, "[0m"  ; ANSI escape code to reset colors
    bg_color    db 27, "[4?m" ; ANSI escape code for ??? background color
                          ^
                           \ ? is a placeholder
```

Your program will work then, but it still **suffers from repeating itself**!
You can easily simplify this code enormously by using a *placeholder in the escape sequence* (I used the question mark). And once the user supplies a valid digit '1' through '5', you just copy it over the placeholder and output the lot. No need to first convert the digit character into its number value.

```
    ; Read the user input
    mov   eax, 0        ; sys_read
    mov   edi, 0        ; stdin
    mov   rsi, number
    mov   edx, 1        ; read one byte
    syscall

    ; Patch escape sequence and write it
    mov   rsi, error_message
    mov   edx, error_message_len
    movzx eax, byte [number]
    cmp   al, '1'
    jb    WriteMsg
    cmp   al, '5'
    ja    WriteMsg
    mov   rsi, bg_color
    mov   edx, 5        ; length of the string
    mov   [rsi + 3], al ; This overwrites the placeholder

    ; Changes the background color OR displays error message
WriteMsg:
    mov   eax, 1        ; sys_write
    mov   edi, 1        ; stdout
    syscall

exit_program:
    ; Exit the program
    mov   eax, 60       ; sys_exit
    xor   edi, edi      ; exit code 0
    syscall
```